# A hard integral $\int\frac{(x^4-1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^8+1} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

This integtare is very hard for me，I do not known how to deal with it.

$$\int\frac{(x^4-1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^8+1} \mathrm{d}x$$

*I use “mathematica” and obtain this*
[image]

**next the “maple” ：**
[image]

the “maple” tell me it's a **Elementary function**

Comment: Where’s the question from, and what have you already tried besides using computer algebra systems? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Comment: @RyanG the question is from a “qq group” I use Basic integration method，it could not help me

Comment: @RyanG The denominator is a high degree polynomial，it seem very hard to factor it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

$$\frac2{x^8+1}=\frac1{x^4+1}\left( \frac1{x^4+\sqrt2x^2+1}+  \frac1{x^4-\sqrt2x^2+1}\right)
$$
Then
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{(x^4-1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^8+1} \> dx \\
=& \frac12 \int\frac{\frac{x^4-1}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}dx}{x^4+\sqrt2x^2+1}
 +\frac12 \int\frac{\frac{x^4-1}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}dx}{x^4-\sqrt2x^2+1}\\
 =& \frac12\int\frac{d\sqrt{ x^2+\frac1{x^2}}}{x^2+\frac1{x^2}+\sqrt2}
+\frac12 \int\frac{d\sqrt{ x^2+\frac1{x^2}}}{x^2+\frac1{x^2}-\sqrt2}\\
=& \frac1{2\sqrt[4]2}\tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{ x^2+\frac1{x^2}} }{\sqrt[4]2 } - \frac1{2\sqrt[4]2}\coth^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{ x^2+\frac1{x^2}} }{\sqrt[4]2 }+C
\end{align}

Comment: Pretty good !..

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{(x^4-1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^8+1}=x\cdot\dfrac{\left(1-\dfrac1{x^4}\right)\sqrt{x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}}}{x^4+\dfrac1{x^4}}$$

Set $x^2=y$ to find

$$\int\dfrac{(x^4-1)\sqrt{x^4+1}}{x^8+1}dx=\dfrac12\int\dfrac{\left(1-\dfrac1{y^2}\right)\sqrt{y+\dfrac1y}}{\left(y+\dfrac1y\right)^2-2}dy$$

Now choose $\sqrt{y+\dfrac1y}=u\implies y+\dfrac1y=u^2$

Comment: you forgot a integrand

Comment: @person, Thanks for your observation

Comment: @labbhattacharjee it could not deal with it

Comment: @我心永恒,  Use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html  $$\dfrac{u^2}{u^4-2}=\dfrac a{u^2-\sqrt2}+\dfrac b{u^2+\sqrt2}$$